# Should WSUS show a server as requiring an update that has been approved for removal?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, windows-update, automatic-updates

I have marked an update in WSUS for removal from all machines.

After the update has been removed from the machines, in WSUS they still show that they require 1 update. When checking what the update is, it is the one that I marked for removal.

It's approval status is "Removal" and its status is "Not Installed".

Is that expected behaviour? I would have imagine it would show as not needed, and thus not throw out my update compliance percentages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is expected behavior. The "removal" update looks and is treated just like an normal update scheduled to be installed (i.e. it can be declined by the user if they have permissions to do so, a reboot may be required after the update is "installed", etc.).

Comment: I see, so if an update approved, regardless of whether it is marked for install or removal, the machines will show it as a needed update? I would have liked to think that it will show as not needed after it meets the install state, in this case removal.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the case. Somewhat unsettling, isn't it? It definitely feels weird to have an "update" for removing an update, but that's basically what it is.

Comment: It's more just frustrating that my report tells me most, if not all, of my servers are requiring updates. When I check, it lists just this one. I guess my solution is, remove it from all servers, then mark it as declined. Thanks.